# App settings attributes missing in "Settings" app of device - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, settings, settings.bundle

I had made a settings.bundle file in my project with some attributes in it. It was working fine and I could find all attributes in device's "Settings" app until I moved the file from one folder to another in my project hierarchy. Now, "Settings" app does show my app name in it, but there are no attributes in it.

Edit:
I have cleaned, build my project several times. Also deleted app from device, reinstalled it but the problem is still there.

I need to know the problem and reason why it has happened.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delete the app and then install it

Comment: I did it several times.. clean project, rebuild but didn't make any difference

Comment: Check if `Settings.bundle` is present in the `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put the Settings bundle wherever you want.  It needs to be in the top level diretory of your app's bundle.

[from the manual:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)

> A Settings bundle has the name Settings.bundle and resides in the
>   top-level directory of your app’s bundle.